# PHP PDO: Protect dynamic identifiers against SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Currently I'm working on a concept for a simplistic tool to perform some »maintenance« database operations (drop/truncate/copy tables etc.) written in PHP.

That necessarily requires identifiers in SQL statements to be dynamic user input. While prepared statements are perfect for separating SQL statements from user input for any comparative values, they are not meant to be used for identifiers like table or column names. (That means, I [*can't* use](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) prepared statements to prepare identifiers.)

A common way to secure dynamic identifiers is whitelisting but this requires a static and known database structure. For example I want to implement a command like `Copy table A and name it B`. The interesting part here is the `B`.

Supposing the user is authenticated and allowed to perform this action, how can I protect this from SQL injection? Is that even possible?

I found [an approach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php#112169) that suggests to simply quote grave accents (`) in any identifier like this:

```
$table_name        = 'origin_table'; // can be checked against existing tables
$copy_table_name   = 'user_input';
$quoted_table_name = '`' . str_replace( '`', '``', $copy_table_name ) . '`';
$sql_statement     = "CREATE TABLE {$quoted_table_name} LIKE {$table_name}";
```

Is that a sufficient protection against possible SQL injections?

**Update**

`PDO::quote()` (mentioned in an answer) is not an option. It does not escape grave accents (`):

```
$user_input = 'table`; TRUNCATE TABLE users --';
var_dump( $pdo->quote( $user_input ) );
//string(33) "'table`; TRUNCATE TABLE users --'"
```

**Update 2**
The PostgreSQL extension has a function for exactly that purpose: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php

Comment: Yes, but as long as the complete string is considered as identifier, functions like `CHAR(96)` are not interpreted by MySQL. (Edit: The comment I answered was removed)

Comment: Thinking aloud: I would have the users enter  the table and column names in a form. Now, these can be validated for nonsense characters and codes. They can then be easily checked for a match with the `mysql data dictionary`. Any mismatches then error. I would also have a 'whitelist' of tables and / or columns. It is a fairly simple task to generate the required SQL from the information provided. ie. Think of `query builders`?

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks, I'll deal with these subjects. An optimal solution would be to have a Method like `TableCopier::copyTables( $src, $dest )`. I sure can write a comment to this method: «DON'T PASS UNFILTERED VALUES TO IT!». But this won't protect it from getting used out there and creating SQL vulnerabilities in the wild.

Comment: I misunderstand. The input from the form must be valid table and column names otherwise they will not match with the [mysql data dictionary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You always want to escape ` identifiers, even table names and field names, as maybe tomorrow they will be reserved words and break your query. As long as you are using prepared statements (PDO, mysqli, or whatever) you will be fine. Note that PDO won't allow to escape table or field names.

You just need to fine grain your filtering mechanism, as to what table name, etc is allowed and not.

BTW: don't do it like you are tring to do: "CREATE TABLE {$quoted_table_name} LIKE {$table_name}";.. user prepared statements with placeholders (?, or :name, etc.)

**EDIT:**
Since you need to secure identifiers, I see 2 ways:

1. surround them with (`)
2. Filtering & escaping incoming values (mysql_real_escape_string or better). Filtering will include striping away any unnecessary characters (you might want to allow only letters [a-z]+ or letters with digits.

Comment: PDO prepared statements are not feasible [because](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): »Parameter markers can represent a complete data literal only.« (but not identifiers.)

Comment: you escape then in regular mysql, PDO takes care of parameters and query seperation. But back to your question, in plain what is the query you are executing? Aren't you just taking table names as input and executing query? I don't see where is the problem?

Comment: The query is in fact not relevant. The question is, how to safely use user input for _identifiers_ (table names, column names) in SQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

As you mention the quote() function for PDO can be used to escape both the column names as well as data. Alternatively using prepared statements such as CREATE TABLE ? LIKE ? and then just execute the query.

Comment: PDO prepared statements are not feasible [because](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): »Parameter markers can represent a complete data literal only.« (but not identifiers.) The `quote()` method would require to strip the first and last `'` from the string which shows me that I use it not in a way it is meant to be used. Also the comment I linked in my question stated that there is a difference in escaping identifiers and escaping »strings«.